# Can my multiple processes be better regulated so that they finish at (almost) the same time?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have the following multiprocessing code

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(maxtasksperchild=20)
likelihoods = pool.map_async(do_comparison, itertools.combinations(clusters, 2)).get()
condensed_score_matrix = [1 / float(l) if l != 0 and l < 5 else 10 for l in likelihoods]
spectra_names = [c.get_names()[0] for c in clusters]
pool.close()
```

The problem with this code is that the different processes do not finish at the same time. I'm using eight processes. There can be 20-30+ minutes between the first process finishing and the last process finishing, with the last process running alone for a big part of that time. It would be much quicker if the workload would be redivided to processes that are finished, so that all cores are used the whole time.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way workload is divided can be controlled with the `chunksize` parameter of map_async.

By omitting it you are currently using the default behavior which is roughly `chunksize = num_tasks / (num_processes * 4)`, so on average each process will only receive 4 chunks.

You can start by setting the chunk size to 1 to validate that it properly distributes workload and then gradually increase it until you stop seeing a performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to experiment with `.imap_unordered` using different `chunksize` values.
More [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered).